# Unexpected problem with some CSS styles on GeoServer for OSM data

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, css

My layerset went wrong after mapproxy caching. Some layers are not rendering, and one of them shows this error message when I want to watch a preview:

```
<ServiceException>The requested Style can not be used with this layer. The style specifies an attribute of water and the layer is: test_osm:water </ServiceException>

</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

CSS code of this style:

```
*{ 
  fill: #91f1ff;

}

[@scale > 5000001] [name='Байкал' or water='sea' or natural = 'coastline']{ 
 fill: #91f1ff;

}

[@scale < 5000001] [@scale > 500001][water='sea' or water='canal' or water='reservoir' or water='canal' or water='lake' or water='cove' or water='river' or natural = 'water' or waterway ='riverbank']{ 
 fill: #91f1ff;

}



[@scale < 500001][water='sea' or water='canal' or water='reservoir' or water='canal' or water='lake' or water='cove' or water='river' or natural = 'water' or waterway ='riverbank' or water = 'pond']{
 fill: #91f1ff;
}
```

What could be the problem? Validation is OK and CSS files really exist on workspaces/myworkspace/styles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was found. No problem with CSS and GeoServer. Problem with datasource - PostgreSQL DB. Part of data was droped. So GeoServer can't render data which doesn't exist.